# concate php variable

Tags: php, javascript

When concatenate php variable result not showing.

```
$a = 5;
$b = 4;
$o = '+';

echo $a.$o.$b;
result showing 5+4; but i want show result 9
```

How can i do this, anybody can help me out. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'+' is a string, so if you concate it with a number you get a string. You have to look into the value:

```
if ($o == '+') {
    echo $a + $b;
}
```

Or what you probably want:

```
switch ($o) {
    case "+":
        echo $a + $b;
        break;
    case "-":
        echo $a - $b;
        break;
    case "*":
        echo $a * $b;
        break;
    case "/":
        echo $a / $b;
        break;
    default:
        echo 0;
}
```

Comment: perhaps also `default: echo 0;` at the end of the switch, if you need to handle cases other than +-*/

Comment: this is working good, just for my acknowledgment how php work with this echo $a.$o.$b; i will try with evel also but no result showing.

Comment: See below what Thai said. Use return in eval() to get a result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "[eval()"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function

As in:--

```
echo eval($a.$o.$b)
```

But be careful never "eval" anything that comes from a web page without validation.

Comment: eval is evil. You should not use eval. And if you have to make sure to escape your parameters! `if(in_array($o, array('+', '-', '*', '/'))) echo eval(intval($a).$o.intval($b))`

Comment: Unlike in JavaScript, you need to use `return` in order to get anything out of eval, and a semicolon is required: ["eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php), so `eval('return ' . intval($a) . $o . intval($b) . ';')`. ;)

Comment: Good to know, took a few tries, but got this working. [example](http://www.ideone.com/ZY1V1)

Answer (score 0):

You are concatenating with the string "+", so you get a string. You want to actually add the numbers:

```
$o = $a + $b;
echo $o;
```

Answer (score 0):

concatenate joins strings. If you want normal arithmetic, just use a plus sign:

```
$a = 5;
$b = 4;
echo ($a + $b)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use concatenate PHP automatically set type of parameters STRING. You should write `$c=$b+$a; echo $c;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
function calc($a, $b, $o) {
    $op = array('+', '-');

    if (in_array($o, $op)) 
        return eval('return '.(int)$a.$o.(int)$b.';');

    return False;
}


$a = 5;
$b = 4;
$o = '+';
var_dump(calc($a, $b, $o));
```

But this is very ugly, you should rethink your logic.